# How to survive with: Here is how much of TeX's memory you used?

Tags: errors, memory

I am a rookie of LaTeX. TeXstudio( with TeXLive distribution) is saying to me that:

```
! Emergency stop. 
<*> ./ARelazioneDCP.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

...

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5790 strings out of 493333
 75513 string characters out of 3139194
 170897 words of memory out of 3000000
 9224 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7657 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,9n,56p,247b,1730s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I cannot understand why, I'm inside to each parameter!
Please, there is someone who have had the same problem and should suggest the solution? or something to solve it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The error is earlier that is just tex finishing up telling you how much memory you used which it _always_ does whether or not there is an error, the error message will be earlier in the log

Comment: Thank you David, the only information that i can add is: Emergency stop, to myfile and job aborted!

Comment: really? there is no error in the log file before the lines that you show????

Comment: there are some warnings and a certain point there is message: 
! Emergency stop.
<*> ./ARelazioneDCP.tex
                       
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

Comment: oh you got to the `<*>` that probably means that you ran off the end of the file so no `\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you David, I didn't miss the end of the document, i have forgotten to close one of the script, so it doesn't run off the end of the document! 
Thank you so much David

Answer (score 11):

```
! Emergency stop. <*>
```

means that TeX got to the end of the file and didn't see a command such as `\end{document}` to finish the document (either because the command is missing, or because an earlier error caused it to be missed).

In interactive mode you can type commands to the `*` prompt, but your editor is running TeX in batchmode so once it gets to this prompt it stops.

The memory usage is always shown at the end of a latex log and isn't related to the error in this case.